# What will explode if I really, really want to inherit from an STL container, and I inherit the constructors and delete the new operator?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl

Let's say I go against all the advice I found on this site and elsewhere online, and do something like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using PointType = std::array<double, 3>;
class Point
:
    public PointType 
{
    public: 

        using PointType::PointType;

        Point(const Point& copy)
            :
                PointType(copy)
        {
            std::cout << "Point(const Point&)" << std::endl;
        }

        Point(Point&& rval)
            :
                PointType(rval)
        {
            std::cout << "Point(Point&&)" << std::endl;
        }

        // Prevent PolygonType* p = new Polygon; delete p;
        template<typename ...Args>
        void* operator new (size_t, Args...) = delete;
};

using PolygonType = std::vector<PointType>; 
class Polygon
:
    public PolygonType
{
    public: 

        using PolygonType::PolygonType;

        Polygon(const Polygon& copy)
            :
                PolygonType(copy)
        {
            std::cout << "Polygon(const Polygon&)" << std::endl;
        }

        Polygon(Polygon&& rval)
            :
                PolygonType(rval)
        {
            std::cout << "Polygon(Polygon&&)" << std::endl;
        }

        // Prevent PolygonType* p = new Polygon; delete p;
        template<typename ...Args>
        void* operator new (size_t, Args...) = delete;
};
```

If I am happy with never using **new** with `Point` or `Polygon` or similar types, the deletion of the `new` operator takes care of the problem of the undefined behavior:

```
std::array<double, 3> a = new Point({1., 2., 3.})
delete a;
```

The conditions on `std::vector<PointType>` imposed by algorithms that work on it are the same: the algorithms check if the public interface fits what is done in the algorithm. This is a problem if I want an algorithm (function template) to view this vector of points as an **open chain of line segments**, or a **closed polygon**. This excludes relying on the implicit interface when resolving function template candidates. Also, concepts do not help me when they arrive, because again, the **conditions on the containers are the same**, what I want the algorithms **to do to them** differs. So using concrete types like this and tagging them, on the other hand, makes tag dispatching trivial if I do the tag dispatching [with SFINAE using the new metafunctions from `type_traits`](http://www.drdobbs.com/function-overloading-based-on-arbitrary/184401659) to check if the template argument has been tagged with a specific tag.

Also the old problem of re-typing constructors is gone with the C++11 constructor inheritance.

So, what still explodes when inheriting from STL in such a way that the constructors are inherited and the `new` operator is deleted? There must be something I am not seeing.

Comment: No virtual destructors == UB.

Comment: @Ron even if OP promises to never add member variables?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with deriving from (library) types with non-virtual destructor. However it is a common mistake to use inheritance when aggregation or composition would be acceptable. Inheritance in the given code snippet is really pointless since those classes add nothing to the base.

Comment: @Scheff Yes. C++ is an abstraction. Compilers are super complex. You can't just say "well the derived class has no members so there's nothing for the destructor to do so that'll be fine". Life just isn't that cut and dry. However, this doesn't apply here if polymorphism will never be used.

Comment: @Scheff Not sure what member variables have to do with polymorphic classes. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Ron If the derived class had members then the derived dtor has "work to do", and skipping that work by failing to invoke it (due to missing `virtual` on the base dtor + deletion through ptr-to-base) causes practical problems. Scheff was wondering whether it's still UB without those practical problems. Answer is yes, and that in itself can still cause practical problems... if for no other reason than there is more to object destruction than the dtor, but for more philosophical reasons too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah right. I knew there was a reason I sent that LinkedIn invitation ;)

Comment: @Ron: Stalker! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your object will always be statically- or automatically- allocated (no `new`), then it will be destructed in the same manner, so you don't need a virtual destructor, so this will work as intended.

Deriving from standard containers isn't outright prohibited, it's just dangerous. You seem to have largely mitigated the danger by eliminating the dangerous use case.

Note that if you *did* permit dynamic allocation then delete through a pointer-to-base, you'd still have UB even if the derived class held no state of its own (i.e. had no members). Object lifetime is a lot more complex than just counting data members.

You could still permit dynamic allocation *and just never delete through a pointer-to-base*, but whether that's logistically appropriate for you, not to mention sufficiently protective, simply depends on the context.

---

Anecdote: I *have* occasionally inherited from vector/map in "library code" not intended to be further expanded by anyone else. It's not open-source software, it's a proprietary codebase under my control, so with the liberal use of comments that's fine. Composition is a bit of a pain if you want to pass through the container's entire interface.

Comment: Wasn't the avoidance of `new` just what OP tried to achieve?

Comment: @Scheff Yes, exactly. Hence, "this will work as intended".

Comment: Even if object is dynamically allocated with `new` it does not necessary need virtual destructor. The **only** restriction emerging from lack of virtual destructor is that pointer to base object can not hold ownership. And even when such a case occurs it would be a user code error, not an issue with class itself (similar to mixing `new` and `delete[]` for example). I have no idea why people always bring virtual destructor when answering questions about inheriting from stdlib classes...

Comment: @VTT: That's right. Indeed, in the case referred to in my anecdote, I simply made sure not to hold owning base pointers (and in context there was no reason to do so). Hence this is purely a "safety"/"danger" issue, not a hard constraint. But it's still one worth remembering.

Comment: @VTT: _"I have no idea why people always bring virtual destructor when answering questions about inheriting from stdlib classes.."_ Because they want to write safe classes that can't be trivially abused by any of the scores of numpties out there! In general, this is a noble goal. However, for me, it does come a little too close for comfort to the "make every destructor virtual" nonsense that was kicking around a decade or two ago: YAGNI sometimes applies too.

Comment: I want exactly the same interface, and I don't need any data members. All I want is to be able to differentiate things like `area(polygon)` and `area(pointChain)`, where `polygon` and `pointChain` are exactly the same vectors of points. The algorithm then uses the SFINAE stuff I linked to, to decide if he should return an area, or scream "Area (polygonChain) is deleted!". The storage is exactly the same, it's about recognizing topology.

Comment: @tmaric And I'd say that's a valid use case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: OK, clear, thank you, and also thanks to everyone that commented, I learned something again today, so it is a good day. :)